# Is there any way to increase the font of a string while writing to a file in XCode for Cocoa application?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to write data to a text file and save it to myDocuments. I am able to do the former part with out much difficulty but when i open the file the text seems to be very small. Is there any way to increase the font size while performing the writing operation so that it is more legible?

```
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-16s %-16s ",[[item valueForKey:@"m_po_num"] UTF8String],[date UTF8String]];

        [aString appendString:string];

        [dateformatter release];

    //writing to a file

    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = @"WeeklyReport.txt";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: Traditionally, a "txt" file does not contain any font information -- it's pure character data.

Comment: really hard to answer this questions... how do you understand text to be formatted in a .txt file?

Comment: Oops thanks a lot for the answer... in the awake of the issue i skipped the basic fact about .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font in a plain text will be defined by the editor you will use to read it.

As you are writing a .txt text via `writeToFile`, it will be a plain text file, not a formatted file like a .doc (Microsoft Word) or .pages.

Comment: So if i use .doc can i change the font at my will??? If possible can guide me on how to save the file as .pdf rather that .txt